# SQL Select Upcoming Birthdays

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a stored procedure to select employees who have birthdays that are upcoming.

`SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Birthday > @Today AND Birthday < @Today + @NumDays`

This will not work because the birth year is part of Birthday, so if my birthday was '09-18-1983' that will not fall between '09-18-2008' and '09-25-2008'.

Is there a way to ignore the year portion of date fields and just compare month/days?

This will be run every monday morning to alert managers of birthdays upcoming, so it possibly will span new years.

Here is the working solution that I ended up creating, thanks Kogus.

```
SELECT * FROM Employees 
WHERE Cast(DATEDIFF(dd, birthdt, getDate()) / 365.25 as int)
    - Cast(DATEDIFF(dd, birthdt, futureDate) / 365.25 as int) 
<> 0
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

*Note: I've edited this to fix what I believe was a significant bug.  The currently posted version works for me.*

This should work after you modify the field and table names to correspond to your database.

```
SELECT 
  BRTHDATE AS BIRTHDAY
 ,FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,EMP.BRTHDATE,GETDATE()) / 365.25) AS AGE_NOW
 ,FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,EMP.BRTHDATE,GETDATE()+7) / 365.25) AS AGE_ONE_WEEK_FROM_NOW
FROM 
  "Database name".dbo.EMPLOYEES EMP
WHERE 1 = (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,EMP.BRTHDATE,GETDATE()+7) / 365.25))
          -
          (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,EMP.BRTHDATE,GETDATE()) / 365.25))
```

Basically, it gets the # of days from their birthday to now, and divides that by 365 (to avoid rounding issues that come up when you convert directly to years).

Then it gets the # of days from their birthday to a week from now, and divides that by 365 to get their age a week from now.

If their birthday is within a week, then the difference between those two values will be 1.  So it returns all of those records.

Comment: I'm not sure how to edit your answer, but instead of dividing by 365, you need to divide by 365.25 and then cast to an int.  Leap year, screwing everything up again.

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right, and I had another bug in there too.  The ability to edit other people's posts comes with a certain reputation score.  Check this link out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-unofficial-faq

Comment: Found a more recent answer from below I liked better, thought I'd share: SELECT * FROM User WHERE (DATEDIFF(dd, getdate(), DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yyyy, birthdate, getdate()), birthdate)) + 365) % 365 <= <number of days>

Comment: @Edyn: Nice! but a little messy ;-)

Comment: The prior comment is off slightly for very specific infrequent dates... here is the fix: SELECT * FROM User 
WHERE (DATEDIFF(dd, getdate(), DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yyyy, birthdate, getdate()) + 1, birthdate))) % 366 <= <number of days>

Answer (score 17):

In case someone is still looking for a solution in **MySQL** (slightly different commands), here's the query:

```
SELECT
 name,birthday,
 FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()),birthday) / 365.25) AS age_now,
 FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()),INTERVAL 30 DAY),birthday) / 365.25) AS age_future

FROM user

WHERE 1 = (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()),INTERVAL 30 DAY),birthday) / 365.25)) - (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()),birthday) / 365.25))

ORDER BY MONTH(birthday),DAY(birthday)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this mysql translation! :D

Answer (score 11):

Best use of datediff and dateadd. No rounding, no approximates, no 29th of february bug, nothing but date functions

1. `ageOfThePerson = DATEDIFF(yyyy,dateOfBirth, GETDATE())`
2. `dateOfNextBirthday = DATEADD(yyyy,ageOfThePerson + 1, dateOfBirth)`
3. `daysBeforeBirthday = DATEDIFF(d,GETDATE(), dateofNextBirthday)`

Thanks to @Gustavo Cardoso, new definition for the age of the person

1. `ageOfThePerson = FLOOR(DATEDIFF(d,dateOfBirth, GETDATE())/365.25)`

Comment: The way that you calculate the person age is not correct. It is because your diff the year only. So if someone have born on 12/1990 and we are on 04/2010 it will calculate the person age as 30.

Comment: this method has some issues, try using following scenario:
<br/><br/>
DECLARE thisJoiningDate DATE = '2011-12-05'<br/>
DECLARE EmploymentDuration DECIMAL(18,2)<br/>
DECLARE DateOfNextAnniversary DATE<br/>
DECLARE DaysBeforeAnniversary INT<br/><br/>


SET EmploymentDuration = DATEDIFF(MONTH, thisJoiningDate, GETDATE())<br/>  
SET DateOfNextAnniversary = DATEADD(MONTH, EmploymentDuration + 12, thisJoiningDate)  <br/>
SET DaysBeforeAnniversary = DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), DateOfNextAnniversary)<br/><br/>

SELECT thisJoiningDate, EmploymentDuration, DateOfNextAnniversary, DaysBeforeAnniversary

Comment: @tjaank, I gave it a try, but where is the additional problem? And there is no concept such as EmploymentDuration or JoiningDate in the question.

Comment: @Gustavo Cardoso, you are right, to my surprise! I updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 4):

Liked the approach of @strelc, but his sql was a bit off. Here's an updated version that works well and is simple to use:

```
SELECT * FROM User 
WHERE (DATEDIFF(dd, getdate(), DATEADD(yyyy, 
    DATEDIFF(yyyy, birthdate, getdate()) + 1, birthdate)) + 1) % 366 <= <number of days>
```

edit 10/2017: add single day to end

Comment: This is flawed. Given a running date of 2015-03-01 and a date of birth of 2012-02-29 the result is 364. Adding 364 days to 2012-02-29 gives 2013-02-27 which is incorrect as it should be returned as 2013-02-28.

Comment: @rrrr You're thinking of it backwards... it should be 2015-03-01 + 364 which is 2016-02-28. However, you were correct that it was flawed, since it was looking backward at leap years instead of forward. I have adjusted it to work correctly.

Comment: @Edyn The select below returns 365, it seems to be off by a day: 
`code` DECLARE @Date DATE = '2018-2-28', @BirthDate DATE = '1960-02-29', @DaysFromBirthDate INT =0
SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, @Date, DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yyyy, @BirthDate, @Date) + 1, @BirthDate) ) % 366 `code`

Comment: @user3800174 Technically that's correct. Since there isn't a leap year for 2018 then it assumes the birthday is the 28th and looks for the next one that matches which is 2019-02-28 and is 365 days away. If you run the same query but using 2020-02-28 as the birthday, you'll get 0 which is correct.

Comment: So using 1960-02-28 returns 365 as well, which isn't correct, they seem to be off by one day :) `code`DECLARE @Date DATE = '2018-2-28', @BirthDate DATE = '1960-02-28', @DaysFromBirthDate INT =0
SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, @Date, DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yyyy, @BirthDate, @Date) + 1, @BirthDate) ) % 366 `code`

Comment: I see what you mean... edited to add a single day to end of calc. This should solve the issue.

Comment: Did you mean: birthdate)) + 1) % 366 ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `DAYOFYEAR` function but be careful when you want to look for January birthdays in December.  I think you'll be fine as long as the date range you're looking for doesn't span the New Year.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry didn't see the requirement to neutralize the year.

```
select * from Employees
where DATEADD (year, DatePart(year, getdate()) - DatePart(year, Birthday), Birthday)
      between convert(datetime, getdate(), 101) 
              and convert(datetime, DateAdd(day, 5, getdate()), 101)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is using "365.25" soon or later would be fail.

So I test the working solution using "365.25"
And It don't return the same numbers of rows for every case.
Here an example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94c3ce/7

test with year 2016 and 2116 and you will see the difference. I only can post one link but change de /7 by /8 to see both queries. (/10 and /11 for the first answer)

So, I suggest this another query, where the point is determinate next birthday from a starting date and then compare if it is in my range of interest.

```
SELECT * FROM Employees 
WHERE 
CASE WHEN (DATEADD(yyyy,DATEDIFF(yyyy, birthdt, @fromDate),birthdt) < @fromDate )
THEN DATEADD(yyyy,DATEDIFF(yyyy, birthdt, @fromDate)+1,birthdt)
ELSE DATEADD(yyyy,DATEDIFF(yyyy, birthdt, @fromDate),birthdt) END
BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate
```

Answer (score 1):

This is solution for MS SQL Server:
It returns employees with birthdays in 30 days.

```
SELECT * FROM rojstni_dnevi
  WHERE (DATEDIFF   (dd, 
                    getdate(), 
                    DATEADD (   yyyy, 
                                DATEDIFF(yyyy, rDan, getdate()),
                                rDan)
    nex             )
        +365) % 365 < 30
```

Comment: Had to fiddle with the query a bit, but works like a charm. Here's the update (will add as answer too): SELECT * FROM User WHERE (DATEDIFF(dd, getdate(), DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yyyy, birthdate, getdate()), birthdate)) + 365) % 365 <= 30

Comment: The former comment is slightly off for very specific infrequent dates... here is the fix: SELECT * FROM User 
WHERE (DATEDIFF(dd, getdate(), DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yyyy, birthdate, getdate()) + 1, birthdate))) % 366 <= <number of days>

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this. This may save someone's precious time.

```
 select EmployeeID,DOB,dates.date  from emp_tb_eob_employeepersonal 
 cross join dbo.GetDays(Getdate(),Getdate()+7) as dates where weekofmonthnumber>0
 and month(dates.date)=month(DOB) and day(dates.date)=day(DOB)



GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[GetDays]    Script Date: 11/30/2011 13:19:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
--SELECT [dbo].[GetDays] ('02/01/2011','02/28/2011')

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDays](@startDate datetime, @endDate datetime)
RETURNS @retValue TABLE
(Days int ,Date datetime, WeekOfMonthNumber int, WeekOfMonthDescription varchar(10), DayName varchar(10))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @nextDay int
    DECLARE @nextDate datetime 
    DECLARE @WeekOfMonthNum int 
    DECLARE @WeekOfMonthDes varchar(10) 
    DECLARE @DayName varchar(10) 
    SELECT @nextDate = @startDate, @WeekOfMonthNum = DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@startDate),0),@startDate) + 1, 
    @WeekOfMonthDes = CASE @WeekOfMonthNum 
        WHEN '1' THEN 'First' 
        WHEN '2' THEN 'Second' 
        WHEN '3' THEN 'Third' 
        WHEN '4' THEN 'Fourth' 
        WHEN '5' THEN 'Fifth' 
        WHEN '6' THEN 'Sixth' 
        END, 
    @DayName 
    = DATENAME(weekday, @startDate)
SET @nextDay=1
WHILE @nextDate <= @endDate 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @retValue values (@nextDay,@nextDate, @WeekOfMonthNum, @WeekOfMonthDes, @DayName) 
    SELECT @nextDay=@nextDay + 1 
SELECT @nextDate = DATEADD(day,1,@nextDate), 
    @WeekOfMonthNum 
    = DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0, @nextDate),0), @nextDate) + 1, 
    @WeekOfMonthDes 
    = CASE @WeekOfMonthNum 
    WHEN '1' THEN 'First' 
    WHEN '2' THEN 'Second' 
    WHEN '3' THEN 'Third' 
    WHEN '4' THEN 'Fourth' 
    WHEN '5' THEN 'Fifth' 
    WHEN '6' THEN 'Sixth' 
    END, 
    @DayName 
    = DATENAME(weekday, @nextDate) 
    CONTINUE 
END 

WHILE(@nextDay <=31)
BEGIN


    INSERT INTO @retValue values (@nextDay,@nextDate, 0, '', '') 
    SELECT @nextDay=@nextDay + 1

END

    RETURN
END
```

Make a cross join with the dates and check for the comparison of month and dates.

Comment: This won't work if someone has a birthday on Feb 29th and the year generating the dates for Feb is not a leap year.

Answer (score 1):

In less than a month:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE MOD( DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , `date_birth`) /30, 12 ) <1 and (((month(`date_birth`)) = (month(curdate())) and (day(`date_birth`)) > (day (curdate() ))) or ((month(`date_birth`)) > (month(curdate())) and (day(`date_birth`)) < (day (curdate() ))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to extract the day and month parts of the birthday dates.

EDIT: sorry i didn't see that he wasn't using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is T-SQL, use DATEPART to compare the month and date separately.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Alternatively, subtract January 1st of the current year from everyone's birthday, and then compare using the year 1900 (or whatever your epoch year is).

Answer (score 0):

Most of these solutions are close, but you have to remember a few extra scenarios.  When working with birthdays and a sliding scale, you must be able to handle the transition into the next month.

For example Stephens example works great for birthdays up until the last 4 days of the month.  Then you have a logic fault as the valid dates if today was the 29th would be :29, 30, AND then 1, 2, 3 of the NEXT month, so you have to condition for that as well.

An alternative would be to parse the date from the birthday field, and sub in the current year, then do a standard range comparison.

Comment: Re your last alternative: That would cause problems with those whose birthday is Feb 29th...

Comment: Ah yes that would be an issue as well to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Another thought:  Add their age in whole years to their birthday (or one more if their Birthday hasn't happened yet and then compare as you do above.  Use DATEPART and  DATEADD to do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

The edge case of a range spanning the year would have to have special code.

Bonus tip: consider using BETWEEN...AND instead of repeating the Birthday operand.

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME
DECLARE @today DATETIME

SELECT @endDate = getDate()+6, @today = getDate()

SELECT * FROM Employees 
    WHERE 
    (DATEPART (month, birthday) >= DATEPART (month, @today)
        AND DATEPART (day, birthday) >= DATEPART (day, @today))
    AND
    (DATEPART (month, birthday) < DATEPART (month, @endDate)
        AND DATEPART (day, birthday) < DATEPART (day, @endDate))
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with my college project a few years ago. I responded (in a rather weasel way) by splitting the year and the date(MM:DD) in two separate columns. And before that, my project mate was simply getting all the dates and programatically going through them. We changed that because it was too inefficient - not that my solution was any more elegant either. Also, its probably not possible to do in a database that has been in use for a while by multiple apps.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees
WHERE DATEADD(yyyy, DATEPART(yyyy, @Today)-DATEPART(yyyy, Birthday), Birthday) > @Today 
AND DATEADD(yyyy, DATEPART(yyyy, @Today)-DATEPART(yyyy, Birthday), Birthday) < DATEADD(dd, @NumDays, @Today)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nuts!  A good solution between when I started thinking about this and when I came back to answer.  :)

I came up with:

```
select  (365 + datediff(d,getdate(),cast(cast(datepart(yy,getdate()) as varchar(4)) + '-' + cast(datepart(m,birthdt) as varchar(2)) + '-' + cast(datepart(d,birthdt) as varchar(2)) as datetime))) % 365
from    employees
where   (365 + datediff(d,getdate(),cast(cast(datepart(yy,getdate()) as varchar(4)) + '-' + cast(datepart(m,birthdt) as varchar(2)) + '-' + cast(datepart(d,birthdt) as varchar(2)) as datetime))) % 365 < @NumDays
```

You don't need to cast getdate() as a datetime, right?

Answer (score 0):

Upcoming Birthday for the Employee - Sqlserver

```
DECLARE @sam TABLE
(
    EmployeeIDs     int,
    dob         datetime
)
INSERT INTO @sam (dob, EmployeeIDs)
SELECT DOBirth, EmployeeID FROM Employee

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, bd_this_year = DATEADD(YEAR, DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(YEAR, dob), dob)
    FROM @sam s
) d
WHERE d.bd_this_year > DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
AND d.bd_this_year <= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps u in some way....

```
select Employeename,DOB 
from Employeemaster
where day(Dob)>day(getdate()) and month(DOB)>=month(getDate())
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination of a couple of the answers that was tested. This will find the next brithday after a certain date and the age they will be. Also the numdays will limit the range you are looking 7 days = week etc.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,Birthday, @BeginDate) / 365.25) + 1 age,
DATEADD(yyyy, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,Birthday, @BeginDate) / 365.25) + 1, Birthday) nextbirthday, birthday
FROM         table
WHERE     DATEADD(yyyy, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,Birthday, @BeginDate) / 365.25) + 1, Birthday) > @BeginDate  
AND DATEADD(yyyy, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,Birthday, @BeginDate) / 365.25) + 1, Birthday) < DATEADD(dd, @NumDays, @BeginDate)
order by nextbirthday
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve the same is

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SELECT Member.* from vwMember AS Member  
WHERE (DATEADD(YEAR, (DATEPART(YEAR, @StartDate) -
                      DATEPART(YEAR, Member.dBirthDay)), Member.dBirthDay)
BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this for **MySQL**, probably not the most efficient way to query but simple enough to implement.

```
select * from `schema`.`table` where date_format(birthday,'%m%d') >= date_format(now(),'%m%d') and date_format(birthday,'%m%d') < date_format(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY),'%m%d');
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe this ticket has been closed ages ago but for the benefit of getting the correct sql query please have a look.

```
SELECT Employee_Name, DATE_OF_BIRTH
FROM Hr_table 
WHERE 

/**
fetching the original birth_date and replacing the birth year to the current but have to  deduct 7 days to adjust jan 1-7 birthdate.
**/

datediff(d,getdate(),DATEADD(year,datediff(year,DATEADD(d,-7,hr.DATE_OF_BIRTH),getdate()),hr.date_of_birth)) between 0 and 7

-- current date looks ahead to 7 days for upcoming modified year birth date.

order by

-- sort by no of days before the birthday
datediff(d,getdate(),DATEADD(year,datediff(year,DATEADD(d,-7,hr.DATE_OF_BIRTH),getdate()),hr.date_of_birth))
```

Answer (score 0):

Better and easy solution:

```
select * from users with(nolock)
where date_of_birth is not null 
and 
(
      DATEDIFF(dd,
                  DATEADD(yy, -(YEAR(GETDATE())-1900),GETDATE()), --Today
                  DATEADD(yy, -(YEAR(date_of_birth)-1901),date_of_birth)
      ) % 365
) = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution also takes care for birthdays in the next year and the ordering:
(dob = day of birth; bty = birthday this year; nbd = next birthday)

```
with rs (bty) as (
    SELECT DATEADD(Year, DATEPART(Year, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(Year, dob), dob) as bty FROM Employees
),
rs2 (nbd) as (
  select case when bty < getdate() then DATEADD(yyyy, 1, bty) else bty end as nbd from rs
)
select nbd, DATEDIFF(d, getdate(), nbd) as diff from rs2 where DATEDIFF(d, getdate(), nbd) < 14 order by diff
```

This version, which avoids comparison of the dates, could be faster:

```
with rs (dob, bty) as (
    SELECT dob, DATEADD(Year, DATEPART(Year, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(Year, DOB), DOB) as bty FROM employee
),
rs2 (dob, nbd) as (
  select dob,  DATEADD(yyyy, FLOOR(ABS((-1*(SIGN(DATEDIFF(d, getdate(), bty))))+0.1)), bty) as nbd from rs
),
rs3 (dob, diff) as (
  select dob, datediff(d, getdate(), nbd) as diff from rs2
)
select dob, diff  from rs3 where diff < 14 order by diff
```

If the range covers the 29 of February in the next year, then use:

```
with rs (dob, ydiff) as (
  select dob, DATEPART(Year, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(Year, DOB) as ydiff from Employee
),
rs2 (dob, bty, ydiff) as (
  select dob, DATEADD(Year, ydiff, dob) as bty, ydiff from rs
),
rs3 (dob, nbd) as (
  select dob, DATEADD(yyyy, FLOOR(ABS((-1*(SIGN(DATEDIFF(d, getdate(), bty))))+0.1)) +  ydiff, dob) as nbd from rs2
),
rs4 (dob, ddiff, nbd) as (
  select dob, datediff(d, getdate(), nbd) as diff, nbd from rs3
)
select dob, nbd, ddiff from rs4 where ddiff < 68 order by ddiff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `DATEPART`:

```
-- To find out Today's Birthday
DECLARE @today DATETIME
SELECT  @today = getdate()

SELECT *
FROM SMIS_Registration 
WHERE (DATEPART (month, DOB) >= DATEPART (month, @today)
      AND DATEPART (day, DOB) = DATEPART (day, @today))
```

Answer (score 0):

select BirthDate,Name from Employees
order by Case
WHEN convert(nvarchar(5),BirthDate,101) > convert(nvarchar(5),GETDATE(),101) then 2
WHEN convert(nvarchar(5),BirthDate,101) < convert(nvarchar(5),GETDATE(),101) then 3
WHEN convert(nvarchar(5),BirthDate,101) = convert(nvarchar(5),GETDATE(),101) then  1 else 4 end ,convert(nvarchar(2),BirthDate,101),convert(nvarchar(2),BirthDate,105)

Comment: Please explain how your code resolves the problem. And please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will return all next birthday of employee, it is shortest query.

```
SELECT 
    Employee.DOB,
    DATEADD(
                mm, 
                (
                    (
                        (
                            (
                                DATEPART(yyyy, getdate())-DATEPART(yyyy, Employee.DOB )
                            )
                            +
                            (
                                1-
                                (
                                    ((DATEPART(mm, Employee.DOB)*100)+DATEPART(dd, Employee.DOB))
                                    /
                                    ((DATEPART(mm, getdate())*100) + DATEPART(dd, getdate()))
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    *12
                    )
                ), 
                Employee.DOB
            ) NextDOB
FROM 
    Employee 
ORDER BY 
    NextDOB ;
```

Above query will cover all next month excluding current date.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for **SQLite3**:

```
SELECT
    *, 
    strftime('%j', birthday) - strftime('%j', 'now') AS days_remaining
FROM
    person
WHERE :n_days >= CASE
    WHEN days_remaining >= 0 THEN days_remaining
    ELSE days_remaining + strftime('%j', strftime('%Y-12-31', 'now'))
    END
;
```

The solutions dividing by 325.25 to get the age, or bringing the birthdate to the current year etc. didn't work for me.
What this does is computes the delta of the two daysOfTheYear (1-366). If the birthday didn't happen yet this year, you automatically get the correct number of remaining days, which you can compare to.
If the birthday already happened, remaining_days will be negative, and you can get the correct number of remaining days by still adding the total amount of days in the current year. This also correctly handles leap years, since in that case the extra day will be added as well (By using dayOfYear(Dec 31.))

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query for today birthday

```
select * 
from tableName
where DAY(convert(date,GETDATE(),105))=DAY(convert(date,DOB,105))
and month(convert(date,GETDATE(),105))=month(convert(date,DOB,105))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we need the real and the next to compare if it has already passed

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FN_NEXT_BIRTHDAY(@BIRTHDAY DATE)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ACTUAL DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, @BIRTHDAY , GETDATE()), @BIRTHDAY);
    DECLARE @NEXT DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, @BIRTHDAY , GETDATE())+1, @BIRTHDAY);

    RETURN CASE WHEN @ACTUAL > GETDATE() THEN @ACTUAL 
                ELSE @NEXT 
                END;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM  PERSON WHERE  DATE_ADD(BIRTH_DATE,
                          INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(BIRTH_DATE) + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) > DAYOFYEAR(BIRTH_DATE),1,0) YEAR)
                          BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: I am trying it will working properly(sql version:-5.7)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

**Try my solution... I have Informix database...**

```
SELECT person, year(today)-year(birthdate) as years, birthdate,

CASE
WHEN MOD(year(birthdate)+((year(today)-year(birthdate))+1),4)<>0 AND MONTH(birthdate)=2 AND DAY(birthdate)=29 THEN 
   CASE 
   WHEN mdy(month(birthdate), 28, year(birthdate)+((year(today)-year(birthdate))+1))-today >= 365 THEN (mdy(month(birthdate), 28, year(birthdate)+((year(today)-year(birthdate))+1))-today)-365
   WHEN mdy(month(birthdate), 28, year(birthdate)+((year(today)-year(birthdate))+1))-today < 365 THEN mdy(month(birthdate), 28, year(birthdate)+((year(today)-year(birthdate))+1))-today
   END
ELSE
   CASE 
   WHEN mdy(month(birthdate), day(birthdate), year(birthdate)+((year(today)-year(birthdate))+1))-today >= 365 THEN (mdy(month(birthdate), day(birthdate), year(birthdate)+((year(today)-year(birthdate))+1))-today)-365
   WHEN mdy(month(birthdate), day(birthdate), year(birthdate)+((year(today)-year(birthdate))+1))-today < 365 THEN mdy(month(birthdate), day(birthdate), year(birthdate)+((year(today)-year(birthdate))+1))-today
   END
END until

FROM table_name
WHERE mdy(month(birthdate), day(birthdate), 2000) >= mdy(month(today), day(today), 2000)
AND mdy(month(birthdate), day(birthdate), 2000) <= mdy(month(today), day(today), 2000)+30
OR
mdy(month(birthdate), day(birthdate), 2000) <= mdy(month(today), day(today), 2000)-(365-30)
ORDER BY 4, YEAR(birthdate)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_EmployeesGetBirths]
        @Date Date,
        @Days int
    as
    Begin
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        Declare
            @From int = Month(@Date) * 100 + Day(@Date),
            @To int = Month(DateAdd(DD, @Days, @Date)) * 100 + Day(DateAdd(DD, @Days, @Date)),
            @NeutralDate Date = Cast('1900-'+cast(Month(@Date) as nvarchar(2))+'-' + cast(Day(@Date) as nvarchar(2)) as Date)

        Select
            DOB,
            DATEADD(DD, DateDiff(DD, @NeutralDate, DateAdd(YY, 1900-Year(DOB), DOB)), @Date) OnDate
        From
            Employees(nolock)
        Where
            DOB is not null and
            Month(DOB) * 100 + Day(DOB) between @From and @To
        order by
            Month(DOB) * 100 + Day(DOB)
    End
    Go
```

Answer (score -1):

Current months birthday

```
SELECT * FROM tblMember m
WHERE m.GDExpireDate != '' 
AND CONVERT(CHAR(2),CONVERT(datetime, m.dob, 103), 101) = CONVERT(CHAR(2), GETDATE(), 101)    
AND CONVERT(CHAR(2),CONVERT(datetime, m.dob, 103), 103) >= CONVERT(CHAR(2), GETDATE(), 103)
```

Answer (score -1):

Get count of the employee having birthday this month:

```
select COUNT(employeeid) from Employee where month(DateOfBirth) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Answer (score -2):

Better, Add the difference in years to the BIRTHDAY date, to make everything this year, and then do your compares

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE
  DATEADD ( year, YEAR(@Today) - YEAR(@Birthday), birthday) BETWEEN @Today AND @EndDate
```

Comment: This is close, but what if it was at the end of a month, or year.  Say today is December 27, and I want the birthdays for the next 2 weeks.