# php mysql search birthday between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, between

I need to find the birth day of people from the table .. coming in next 7 days from today.
I have a query ..`SELECT * FROM`table`WHERE`dob`LIKE BETWEEN %-08-17 AND %-08-24` but it returns the records whose dates are not submitted in database..i mean the entry is 0000-00-00
I have stored the birthdates in dates format in table. Please Help me finding the bug.

Comment: what is the datatype of date column in your table? date or string?

Comment: then you can use BETWEEN to specify two dates

Comment: A lot of duplicates on this type of question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83531/sql-select-upcoming-birthdays (for SS, but same principle)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this is mysql, I don't know if **[DATE_FORMAT()](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)** can work on this. But give this a try.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%c-%d') 
BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('1983-08-17', '%c-%d') 
AND DATE_FORMAT('1983-08-24', '%c-%d') OR (MONTH('1983-08-17') > MONTH('1983-08-24')
AND (MONTH(dob) >= MONTH('1983-08-17') 
OR MONTH(dob) <= MONTH('1983-08-24')))
```

*any year can be used (just to complete the date format) since year does not matter*

**UPDATE 1**

Tested it on SQLFiddle.com

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c69d8/4)

**UPDATE 2**

I'm sorry for my first answer. I honestly missed to read this line `coming in next 7 days from today`. And I think that was the reason why I was downvoted by `Imre L`. He has his point. The reason why I posted the answer like that was because I thought the OP was asking for the days in between regardless of the `year`. So here is the update.

```
SELECT ....
FROM   ....
WHERE  DATE(dob) BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Hope it's clear now. :D

Comment: Clever. This performs about a tenth of a second better than my idea on my dataset (just a random table with a lot of records and dates). I dig it.

Comment: what if current date is 2012-08-30 and +7 is 2012-09-06 likewise what if current date is 2012-12-30?

Comment: @MetalFrog Tested it and it worked [*SQLFiddle Demo Link*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c69d8/2)

Comment: -1 because it is totally broken on 2 cases: 1) when the year changes in next 7 days 2) when it will be october in next 7 days (its a string comparison)

Comment: Your answer is edited answer is still wrong. Because nobody in the database can possibly have birthdays in the future =)

Answer (score 1):

this will handle correctly cases wen there is a month or year change between the date range:

```
select *
  from people
 where (DAYOFYEAR(dob)+IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())>DAYOFYEAR(dob),1000,0)) 
       between DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) 
           and (DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY)+IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())>DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY),1000,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

By converting the dob date into this year's date you can avoid issues where the period crosses a month or year boundary.  This selects all rows where the birthdate occurs in the coming week:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE concat( year(now()), mid(dob,5,6) ) 
BETWEEN now() AND date_add(now(), interval 7 day)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
str_to_date(DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - YEAR(dob)) YEAR), '%Y-%m-%d') BIRTHDAY,A.*
FROM app_membership A
WHERE str_to_date(DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - YEAR(dob)) YEAR), '%Y-%m-%d') 
      BETWEEN str_to_date('15-10-2017','%d-%m-%Y') and str_to_date('10-11-2017','%d-%m-%Y')
ORDER BY BIRTHDAY ASC;
```

Try this. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Lets list people who born in any month/year between december 14 and august 24. We know its an year before another one. We must count with months in the previous year. It's complex because you may have a problem comparing the month of the starting date with the month of the ending date. However, it may be solved with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM t_users WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(d_birth, '%m-%d') 
BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2017-12-14', '%m-%d') AND 
DATE_FORMAT('2018-08-24', '%m-%d'))

OR(MONTH('2017-12-31') >= MONTH('2018-08-24')
AND (MONTH(d_birth) >= MONTH('2017-12-31') 
OR MONTH(d_birth) <= MONTH('2018-08-24')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple query

SELECT * FROM TEST1 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '04-01' AND '04-30';

https://youtu.be/CaJKmw9NLq0