# How to search birthdate using sql query?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to search **Date of Birth** from my sql server database table. Problem what i am getting is the year of **DOB** will be different and will be latter than current year. If i want to get customer list whose birthday will coming in next 7 days same as facebook birthday reminder.

I have tried to convert `smalldatetime` to `varchar` and used `LIKE` statement with '_' **wild card character**. for example `Convert(Char(10),DOB,103) LIKE "__/02/____'`.  but, it gives me list of customers whose DOB is coming in current month. Also it shows me those data whose birthday has gone previously on current month. I want to only those data whose birthday is coming on next 7 days.

My application has developed in **C#**. if possible to get appropriate result using `DataTable` or `DataView` then please suggest me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Select Upcoming Birthdays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83531/sql-select-upcoming-birthdays) check  [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83531/sql-select-upcoming-birthdays/83783#83783)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this method of date assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/267016/314291), this should work:

<del>select *
    from Customers
    where DATEADD(day, DAY(DOB) -1, 
               DATEADD(month, MONTH(DOB) - 1,
                   DATEADD(year, YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1900, 0)))
        BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND DATEADD(DD, 7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);</del>

.

**Edit**
The above didn't work across the change of year.
This does, although is rather clumsy (Use `@Today` to test scenarios, and then substitute for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` when done):

```
DECLARE @Today DATE = '31 Dec 2013';
select *
from Customers
CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT YEAR(@Today) AS yr
        UNION
        SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(d, 7, @Today))
    ) years
where 
    DATEADD(day, DAY(DOB) -1, 
           DATEADD(month, MONTH(DOB) - 1,
               DATEADD(year, years.yr - 1900, 0)))
    BETWEEN @Today AND DATEADD(DD, 7, @Today);
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f806/2)

The `cross join` will return either this year or this year AND next year if we are near to the end of year, and the UNION will ensure only one row if the year is the same. If 2 years are returned (i.e. we are late in December), then the Between will exclude the customer's DOB which happened earlier this year in January :P There must be a more elegant solution, however ...

Comment: Why not just add the difference in years between the DOB and today to the DOB and match according to that, as posted in my answer? I've used that method countless times before and it always works 100%...

Answer (score 1):

Try fashioning a where clause to your query using the `DATEPART` and `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` functions. The following WHERE clause should get you the desired results:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table]
WHERE DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, [DOB], GETDATE()) +
          CASE
              WHEN DATEPART(mm, GETDATE()) > 
                   DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(dd, 7, GETDATE())) 
               AND DATEPART(mm, GETDATE()) <> DATEPART(mm, [DOB])
                   THEN 1 
              ELSE 0
          END, [DOB]) 
      BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(dd, 7, GETDATE())
```

What that clause does, is it moves the [DOB] value to the current year using `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` and matches it between today and 7 days from today.

EDIT: Amended the clause to cater for cycles over year periods.

Comment: This seems to also miss the edge case where today is 31 December and there is a customer's birthday coming up in the first week of January?. [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c6675/1) (Fiddle updated)

Comment: make that http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/16105/1

Comment: Busy with an amended answer as well - just tested and you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Use the date based functions.

```
//pseudo code
Where Month(birthdate) = 7
and Day(birthdate) = 4
```

will pull up those born on the 4th of July

Comment: This doesn't address the OP, but rather matches a date to a specific day and month. The idea is to get dates between today and 7 days from today, so you can't match it to specific days and/or months.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on my development machine so this is untested, but should point you in the correct direction.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE MONTH(DOB) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND 
(DAY(DOB) BETWEEN DAY(GETDATE()) AND 
DAY(DATEADD(dd, 7, GETDATE())))
```

Note that the `GETDATE()` function gets the current date and time for the current time zone on the machine. To use the UTC date, replace `GETDATE()` with `GETUTCDATE()`.

Comment: This won't work, because as soon as it spans over two months you wont get the correct data.

Comment: @FarligOpptreden Good point. I didn't consider that...

Answer (score 0):

Using StuartLC’s example as a baseline.  How about building up the DOB for each record, but instead of the actual year, use the current year and next year.  This way, you can take the DateDiff for the seven day range over both dates -- which handles the year rollover and is very explicit for its intent.

Example:

```
DECLARE @Today DATE = '31 Dec 2013';

SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE
      cast(
          cast(Month(DOB) AS varchar) + '/' +
          cast(Day(DOB) AS varchar) + '/' +
          cast(Year(@Today) AS varchar) AS Date) BETWEEN @Today AND dateadd(day, 7, @Today)
OR
        cast(
          cast(Month(DOB) AS varchar) + '/' +
          cast(Day(DOB) AS varchar) + '/' +
          cast(Year(@Today) + 1 AS varchar) AS Date) BETWEEN @Today AND dateadd(day, 7, @Today)
```

[Sql Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f806/14/0)