# Get Birthdates of employees for a period of +-30 days

Tags: sql, sapb1

I'm a newbie in SQL. For my SAP B1 add-on I need a SQL query to display Birthdates of employees for a period of +-30days(this will be a user given int at the end).

I wrote a query according to my understanding and it only limits the period only for the current month. Ex:If the current date is 2016.01.15 the correct query should show birthdates between the period of 16th December to 14th February. But I only see the birthdates for January.You can see the query below.

```
SELECT T0.[BirthDate], T0.[CardCode], T1.[CardName], T0.[Name], T0.[Tel1], 
T0.[E_MailL] FROM OCPR T0 INNER JOIN OCRD T1 ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode 
WHERE DATEADD( Year, DATEPART( Year, GETDATE()) - DATEPART( Year, T0.[BirthDate]), 
T0.[BirthDate]) BETWEEN CONVERT( DATE, GETDATE()-30)AND CONVERT( DATE, GETDATE() +30);
```

What are the changes I should do to get the correct result?
Any help would be highly appreciated! :-)

Comment: @Steve Hey in SAP all the employees birthdates are saved in a table called OCPR. So imagine one employee has his birthday on 1957.12.25 saved in this table. What is so wrong in that? Sorry if my bad English gave a wrong idea to you :(

Comment: Now I understandand better

Comment: Try looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83531/sql-select-upcoming-birthdays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT T0.[BirthDate], T0.[CardCode], T1.[CardName], T0.[Name], T0.[Tel1], T0.[E_MailL] 
FROM OCPR T0 INNER JOIN OCRD T1 ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode 
WHERE TO.[BirthDate] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, +30, GETDATE())
```

You can adapt the [answer I've referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83531/sql-select-upcoming-birthdays) in the comments as follows:

```
SELECT T0.[BirthDate], T0.[CardCode], T1.[CardName], T0.[Name], T0.[Tel1], T0.[E_MailL]
FROM OCPR T0 INNER JOIN OCRD T1 ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode
WHERE 1 = (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,TO.Birthdate,GETDATE()+30) / 365.25))
          -
          (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,TO.Birthdate,GETDATE()-30) / 365.25))
```

As per Vladimir's comment you can amend the '**365.25**' to '**365.2425**' for better accuracy if needed.

Comment: This will not give correct result. `BirthDate` can be many years before the current date returned by `GETDATE`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - just realised that, but just found a question that seems to be very similar.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - over a normal lifetime this would not have a dramatic effect, (quarter of a day I think). Unless you're planning to record the time of the employees birth as well then for the purpose of being aware of LIVE employees birthdays in a given period this should be fine. However, for the sake of accuracy it may well be worth adding .2425 instead of .25. I shall update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it in SQL Server, because it has the `DATEADD`, `GETDATE` functions.

Your query returns wrong results when the range of +-30 days goes across the 1st of January, i.e. when the range belongs to two years.

Your calculation

```
DATEADD(Year, DATEPART(Year, GETDATE()) - DATEPART( Year, T0.[BirthDate]), T0.[BirthDate])
```

moves the year of the `BirthDate` into the same year as `GETDATE`, so if `GETDATE` returns `2016-01-01`, then a `BirthDate=1957-12-25` becomes `2016-12-25`. But your range is from `2015-12-01` to `2016-01-30` and adjusted `BirthDate` doesn't fall into it.

There are many ways to take this boundary of the year into account.

One possible variant is to make not one range from `2015-12-01` to `2016-01-30`, but three - for the next and previous years as well:

```
from `2014-12-01` to `2015-01-30`
from `2015-12-01` to `2016-01-30`
from `2016-12-01` to `2017-01-30`
```

One more note - it is better to compare original `BirthDate` with the result of some calculations, rather than transform `BirthDate` and compare result of the function. In the first case optimizer can use index on `BirthDate`, in the second case it can't.

Here is a full example that I tested in SQL Server 2008.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (BirthDate date);

INSERT INTO @T (BirthDate) VALUES
('2016-12-25'),
('2016-01-25'),
('2016-02-25'),
('2016-11-25'),
('2015-12-25'),
('2015-01-25'),
('2015-02-25'),
('2015-11-25'),
('2014-12-25'),
('2014-01-25'),
('2014-02-25'),
('2014-11-25');

--DECLARE @CurrDate date = '2016-01-01';
DECLARE @CurrDate date = '2015-12-31';
DECLARE @VarDays int = 30;
```

I used a variable `@CurrDate` instead of `GETDATE` to check how it works in different cases.

`DATEDIFF(year, @CurrDate, BirthDate)` is the difference in years between `@CurrDate` and `BirthDate`

`DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, @CurrDate, BirthDate), @CurrDate)` is `@CurrDate` moved into the same year as `BirthDate`

The final `DATEADD(day, -@VarDays, ...)` and `DATEADD(day, +@VarDays, ...)` make the range of `+-@VarDays`.

This range is created three times for the "main" and previous and next years.

```
SELECT
    BirthDate
FROM @T
WHERE
    (
        BirthDate >= DATEADD(day, -@VarDays, DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, @CurrDate, BirthDate), @CurrDate))
        AND
        BirthDate <= DATEADD(day, +@VarDays, DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, @CurrDate, BirthDate), @CurrDate))
    )
    OR
    (
        BirthDate >= DATEADD(day, -@VarDays, DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, @CurrDate, BirthDate)+1, @CurrDate))
        AND
        BirthDate <= DATEADD(day, +@VarDays, DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, @CurrDate, BirthDate)+1, @CurrDate))
    )
    OR
    (
        BirthDate >= DATEADD(day, -@VarDays, DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, @CurrDate, BirthDate)-1, @CurrDate))
        AND
        BirthDate <= DATEADD(day, +@VarDays, DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, @CurrDate, BirthDate)-1, @CurrDate))
    )
;
```

**Result**

```
+------------+
| BirthDate  |
+------------+
| 2016-12-25 |
| 2016-01-25 |
| 2015-12-25 |
| 2015-01-25 |
| 2014-12-25 |
| 2014-01-25 |
+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll you know the progress after I test it :)

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified this a little. I have annotated the code where the calculations have been made so looking back in the future you will know what it is doing (often a savior) :).

```
SELECT T0.[BirthDate], 
       T0.[CardCode], 
       T1.[CardName], 
       T0.[Name], 
       T0.[Tel1], 
       T0.[E_MailL]
FROM OCPR T0 
INNER JOIN OCRD T1 
ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode 
WHERE T0.[BirthDate] >= GETDATE()       -- Where the birthday is greater than or equal to today's date
AND   T0.[BirthDate] <= GETDATE() + 30  -- Where the birthday is less than or equal to today's date plus 30 days.
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. I ran your query in SQL Management Studio. It returns empty results.

Comment: This Sql does not check for the year. The year has to be set to the current (and last year if we are in january) year to check it correctly.

Comment: Also, using the 'AND' means Birthdate would have to equal GETDATE() to ever be returned.

Comment: Apologies, i must have misunderstood what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using DAYOFYEAR:

```
SELECT T0.[BirthDate], 
       T0.[CardCode], 
       T1.[CardName], 
       T0.[Name], 
       T0.[Tel1], 
       T0.[E_MailL]
FROM OCPR T0 
INNER JOIN OCRD T1 
ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode
WHERE IF(DayOfYear(T0.[BirthDate]) - DayOfYear(CURDATE()) < 0, DayOfYear(T0.[BirthDate]) - DayOfYear(CURDATE()) + DayOfYear(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),"%Y-12-31")), DayOfYear(T0.[BirthDate]) - DayOfYear(CURDATE())) <= 30
OR IF(DayOfYear(CURDATE()) - DayOfYear(T0.[BirthDate]) < 0, DayOfYear(CURDATE()) - DayOfYear(T0.[BirthDate]) + DayOfYear(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),"%Y-12-31")), DayOfYear(CURDATE()) - DayOfYear(T0.[BirthDate])) <= 30
```