# check whether a birth date is upcoming in a data table

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the question. I am getting the result as number of days from the date of birth till now. but I need whether it is upcoming 5 days from the date now.

```
select *, datediff(DAY , DateOfBirth,GETDATE()) as diff
    From Table_A
    order by DateOfBirth asc
```

Comment: Hi, do you have a question?

Comment: Mysql does not have getdate is this question tagged correctly?

Comment: Was this supposed to be an answer to someone else's question?

Comment: this is the question. i am getting the result as number of days from the date of birth till now. but i need whether it is upcoming 5 days from the date now

Comment: MYSQL or SQLSERVER?

Comment: You could use something like this as a base  `SELECT DATEDIFF(DATE_FORMAT(DateOfBirth, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-%m-%d %T')), NOW()) AS diff` but it doesn't work for cases where the birthday is 1st to 5th of january, for example

Comment: mysql version 2014 p.salmon

Comment: mysql supports getdate()?

Comment: Version 2014 So its SQLServer then

Comment: It is his `sql` but `microsoft sql server` i guess

Comment: yes sql server it is

Comment: Can you please reformat question , add some sample input and expected output data

Comment: I think he is trying to get # of days to birthday from today. so will take into consideration the day of the year.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Select Upcoming Birthdays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83531/sql-select-upcoming-birthdays)

Comment: @vishal . . . How do you know if someone's date of birth will be five days in the future?  The question doesn't make sense.  I am guessing you want birthdays.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_A WHERE DateOfBirth BETWEEN GETDATE()
   AND DATEADD(day,5, Convert(Date,GETDATE()))
```

it will give you all the birthdays in the next 5 days.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the birthdays, you can do something like:

```
DECLARE @dates AS TABLE ( DateOfBirth DATE );
DECLARE @number_of_days INT = 5;

INSERT  INTO @dates
        ( DateOfBirth )
VALUES  ( '20090101' ),
        ( '20090809' ),
        ( '20090816' ),
        ( '20180807' );

SELECT  * ,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, SYSDATETIME(), bd.this_year_birthday)
FROM    @dates d
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(SYSDATETIME()),
                                              MONTH(d.DateOfBirth),
                                              DAY(d.DateOfBirth)) AS this_year_birthday
                    ) bd
WHERE   DATEDIFF(DAY, SYSDATETIME(), bd.this_year_birthday) BETWEEN 0
                                                            AND
                                                              @number_of_days;
```

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding, you need to get upcoming birthdays in next 5 days. In `MySQL` you can do with the query below,

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(DateOfBirth,'%m-%d') AS md 
FROM Table_A 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DateOfBirth,'%m-%d') BETWEEN '08-07' AND '08-12'
ORDER BY md
```

It will return all birthdays between 07 and 12 Aug. Get the current and +5 days at the scripting side.

If you want pure query based solution without any calculation for dates at scripting side, refer following query,

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(DateOfBirth,'%m-%d') AS md 
FROM Table_A 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DateOfBirth,'%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m-%d')
AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY), '%m-%d')
ORDER BY md
```

Comment: by reading the comments under the question it seems that it is needed for SQL Server, not mysql

Comment: It's fine. Someone in the future might bump up to this question for MySQL variant.